# How to mock a method that returns a struct?

Tags: go, gomock

Here's a little `golang` program that connects to localhost via `ssh` and does some `sftp`-like operations. It works fine but I would like to make the `doTheWork()` function more testable.

I've read up on using [gomock](https://github.com/golang/mock) to create mocks for interfaces. So I've already created two interfaces, `Sftper` and `Walker`, and I'm using those instead of calling `sftp`'s methods directly.

What I want to do is mock out all the stuff from `stfp` inside `doTheWork()`. `Close()` is easy because it only returns an `error` (or `nil`). But `Create()` returns [*sftp.File](https://github.com/pkg/sftp/blob/master/client.go#L666) and that is a struct, not an interface. Same with `Walk()` which returns another struct. I would have to create one of these structs in my test code, and that's not really possible without actually calling the real `sftp` library and making a remote connection and creating a remote file, and this is exactly what I am trying to mock out.

What am I missing?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/kr/fs"
    "github.com/pkg/sftp"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

// Sftper helps make things testable
type Sftper interface {
    Close() error
    Create(path string) (*sftp.File, error)
    Lstat(p string) (os.FileInfo, error)
    Walk(root string) *fs.Walker
}

// Walker helps make things testable
type Walker interface {
    Step() bool
    Err() error
    Path() string
}

var sftpclient Sftper
var w Walker

func doTheWork(sftpclient Sftper) {
    defer sftpclient.Close()

    // walk a directory
    w = sftpclient.Walk("/tmp/")
    for w.Step() {
        if w.Err() != nil {
            continue
        }
        log.Println(w.Path())
    }

    // leave your mark
    f, err := sftpclient.Create("hello.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if _, err1 := f.Write([]byte("Hello world!")); err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err1)
    }

    // check it's there
    fi, err := sftpclient.Lstat("hello.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(fi)

}

func main() {
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "myusername",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("mysupersecretpassword"),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    conn, err0 := ssh.Dial("tcp", "localhost:22", config)
    if err0 != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to dial: ", err0)
    }

    // open an SFTP session over an existing ssh connection.
    var err error
    sftpclient, err = sftp.NewClient(conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    doTheWork(sftpclient)
}
```

Comment: [Something like this](https://play.golang.org/p/z89aUW2j78C). *(removed code not needed for the illustration)*

Comment: Works great, thanks.